# Do disconnected remote desktop sessions lock accounts?

Tags: active-directory, rdp

I'm getting an account locked daily - I've read that this could be due to disconnect remote desktop sessions ? Is this true? Is it a group policy setting?

Regards, Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely.  If you've changed your password but have a logged in session with an olld password, you will have issues.