# Windows: How do I log out of a remote desktop that only gives a disconnect option?

Tags: windows-server-2016

The problem with disconnect is it locks my AD account when I change my password. ([Do disconnected remote desktop sessions lock accounts?](https://serverfault.com/questions/394287/do-disconnected-remote-desktop-sessions-lock-accounts))  The remote session only gives me options to "Shutdown", "Restart" and "Disconnect".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Click start, then from your username/icon in the top right corner you can choose "sign out".  The power button has "disconnect, shut down, restart", your user button has "lock, sign out".

If the version of windows you're using doesn't have that icon, open a command or powershell window and type `logoff`

Answer (score 16):

Easy fix: press control-alt-end and click "sign out".

Comment: The problem is that when you have two levels of RDP this operates on first level

Answer (score 2):

Just hit the windows button and type "logoff". Run the command. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try opening up PowerShell and running the following command to open up the Windows Security dialog:

```
(New-Object -COM Shell.Application).WindowsSecurity()
```

Then click the "Sign Out" button.